# How can multiple subdomain be redirected to only one specific subdomain using CloudFlare?

Tags: redirects, subdomain, cloudflare

How can i redirect multiple subdomain to one specific subdomain using CloudFlare page rule.

Note: redirect without changing the URL path (only sub domain change)

For example:

- `sub1.site.example/article`
- `sub2.site.example/article`
- `sub3.site.example/article`

into:

`newsub.site.example/article`

---

If any of the 3 examples URLs is typed in browser, it should automatically redirect to `newsub.site.example`

How can this be done using cloudflare page rule? Please help

Comment: To clarify you want exactly those three subdomains  to redirect or every subdomain except `newsub`?

Comment: Is Cloudflare configured as the CDN for your `newsub` subdomain?

Comment: Yes i want those 3 subdomain to redirect to newsub

Comment: yes cloudflare is used as cdn

Comment: Here is an example of a live website if you type this address: https://w1.voirfilm.plus/films/breach-2021.html  it automatically redirect to https://ww1.voirfilm.plus/films/breach-2021.html keeping the path, i want to know how to do this please help me

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare has the documentation about page rules here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-

You might be able to use a single page rule to do this, if you don't mind redirect any subdomain that starts with `sub`.  You could use two wildcards, one for number in the subdomain and the other for the URL path.    The first wildcard becomes `$1` and the second becomes `$2`.  Because you are discarding information about the subdomain, you would not use `$1` in the resulting URL, but you would use the `$2` to preserve the path:

**If the URL matches:**  `sub*.site.example/*`
**The settings are:** Forwarding URL, 301 Permanent Redirect
`newsub.site.example/$2`

If your subdomains don't match a pattern, or if you have other subdomains that you want to keep that fit the pattern, you would need to use multiple page rules.  With multiple page rules you only use one wildcard, so the path is `$1` is the resulting URL.   A free Cloudflare account only gets three page rules, so this would use up all of them.

**If the URL matches:**  `sub1.site.example/*`
**The settings are:** Forwarding URL, 301 Permanent Redirect
`newsub.site.example/$1`

**If the URL matches:**  `sub2.site.example/*`
**The settings are:** Forwarding URL, 301 Permanent Redirect
`newsub.site.example/$1`

**If the URL matches:**  `sub3.site.example/*`
**The settings are:** Forwarding URL, 301 Permanent Redirect
`newsub.site.example/$1`

Comment: Wooow dude you are a legend ✨

Comment: I just try it but it say forwarding url matches target would cause redirect loop

Comment: My sub domains is ww1.nktube.ga   ww2.nktube.ga and ww3.nktube.ga, i want all the three to point to ww4.nktube.ga with path  please legend help me with this

Comment: You can't use the first option with the wild card in the subdomain because the wild card matches the new subdomain as well. You'll have to use the three separate rules.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your helps legend✨